# Inhale a cigarette smoke

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Is there a word in English to express one or multiple inhales(?) of a cigarette?

Seems like "inhale" is not the proper word for it. I want a word to use in such a situation

> "Dude, don't finish(?) your cigarette, leave me something for two [inhales] at least."

Also, "don't finish your cigarette" sounds awkward to me, is there a more specific word in terms of smoking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is this word given in [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/drag)

> **drag**
>   NOUN
>
> **3** *informal* An act of inhaling smoke from a cigarette.
>   *he took a long drag on his cigarette*

So you can say

> Dude, don't finish your cigarette, save me a couple of **drags** at least.

Or avoiding the "finish"

> Dude, don't throw away that [butt](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/butt), save me a couple of **drags** at least.
>
> Dude, don't [stub](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/stub) out that cigarette, save me a couple of **drags** at least.

---

In the case of a marijuana cigarette, it could be

> Dude, don't [bogart](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/bogart) that joint, save me a couple of [**tokes**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/toke) at least.

Answer (score 1):

Ewww,  nasty image, but could say "...leave me a couple of puffs."

Inhale is a verb, inhalation is the corresponding noun, but it is non-count (smoke is also non-count, unless used as a euphemism for cigarette)

"Don't finish your cigarette" is correct and idiomatic.